# Use a defined named range from one spreadsheet in another

Tags: excel, vba

In a masterfile I have the worksheet XXXX, which the range C2:C3 contains the names of two tables. I store those names in the array tba which is a variant variable.

```
Private Sub ORSA_REPORT_Click()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim SummaryWb As Workbook
    Dim tba As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set SummaryWb = Workbooks.Open("I:\XXX\XXXXX.xlsx") ' <--- I open this workbook
                                                        '      which contains the tables
                                                        '      I need to copy

    ThisWorkbook.Activate

    tba = Worksheets("XXX").Range("C2:C3") ' <--- Please see below a screenshot
                                           '      with the names

    SummaryWb.Activate

    For i = 1 To 2

        Set rng = Range(tba(i, 1)) ' <--- in the tba are names which i take them from
                                   '      the masterworkbook but i want to use them
                                   '      in the workbook whichg contains the tables

        rng.Copy

        SummaryWb.Worksheets("New").Cells(i, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

    Next i
```

I want to activate the SummaryWb and use the names from the tba in the SummaryWb to define the rng which is a range variable.

I made an extensive research but I could not figure it out.

Example:

The first name range which is in the masterworkbook is Name1
The second name range which is in the masterworkbook is Name2
 --> Please note that only the names are in that file.

Next the actual range is in the other workbook. For example:

In workbook2 I have the A1:B5 named as Name1 and C1:D5 named as Name2.

I store the two names from the workbook1 in an array, the tba.

I want to set the rng to be equal with the ranges represented by the entries of the tba.

Comment: I don't understand your code. First rng is a range then the next line it's a string..?

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer.  Set rng=Range(tba(i,1)) has the name ranges. The next line what i want to do is to write "OK" in the named ranges. The tba is: tba(1,1)=NameRange1, tba(2,1)=NameRange2, where NameRange is A1:B5 and NameRange2 is C1:D5. Is it clear now? If not i explain further!

Comment: You say `Range("C2:C3")` contains the name of 2 tables. Do you mean ListObject tables or Worksheets? Please [edit] and show the data you have in that range. And then what do you expect of `Range(tba(i, 1))` if you use it like that it must be a range address in `tba(i, 1)` and not a "table" name. • At best provide a [mcve] and show which input data you use, and tell which errors you get. Note that code in comments is not readable (instead please [edit] the original question).

Comment: @Andreas (without T) for your interest that is valid code. If `rng` is a range object and you write `rng = "OK"` it defaults to `rng.value`. So it is actually the same as `rng.Value = "OK"`. Nevertheless the question is pretty unclear :)

Comment: Did not know that @Pᴇʜ but in my opinion it will make the code hard to read like that.

Comment: I just changed the question if you could see it again please.

Comment: Can you share a sample of the values held in `Worksheets("XXX").Range("C2:C3")`?  Are these names of a named range or are these addresses of a range? If they are names of a named range, do those names exist in the workbook `Workbooks.Open("I:\XXX\XXXXX.xlsx")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `.Activate` instead specify workbook and worksheet for **every** range object. If you do that it is clear what happens.

```
Private Sub ORSA_REPORT_Click()
    Dim SummaryWb As Workbook
    Set SummaryWb = Workbooks.Open("I:\XXX\XXXXX.xlsx")     

    Dim tba As Variant
    tba = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("XXX").Range("C2:C3").Value
    'eg tba is then:
    'tba(1, 1) = "Name1"
    'tba(2, 1) = "Name2"


    For i = 1 To 2
        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = Workbooks("Workbook2").Worksheets("SheetName").Range(tba(i, 1)) 

        rng.Copy

        SummaryWb.Worksheets("New").Cells(i, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    Next i
End Sub
```

So make sure for every Range object that you specify which workbook/worksheet it is in. If it is in the workbook the VBA code is in then you can use `ThisWorkbook` instead of `Workbooks("NameOfWorkbook")`.

Note that if you use `Set rng = Workbooks("Workbook2").Worksheets("SheetName").Range(tba(i, 1))` then the named ranges `Name1` and `Name2` must exist in worksheet `SheetName` of `Workbook2`.